# How can I pass in parameters for multiple controls to a function that returns a Manipulate?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, warning-messages

For instance, I have a some "commands" that I use regularly, for example:

```
  Manipulate[Plot[fun, {var, ldv, udv}, PlotRange -> {{plx1, plx2}, {ply1, ply2}}],    {av , lav, avu}].
```

So I define a custom function to avoid all the parethesis and braces as follows:

```
  cman[fun_, var_, ldv_, udv_, plx1_, plx2_, ply1_, ply2_, av_, lav_, uav_ ] := 
  Manipulate[Plot[fun, {var, ldv, udv}, PlotRange -> {{plx1, plx2}, {ply1, ply2}}] ,  {av , lav, uav}].
```

This works exactly how I want it to, for this special case. However what do we do if we have more manipulation variables. For instance I would like to similarly flatten out the following code,

```
  Manipulate[Plot[fun, {var, ldv, udv}, PlotRange -> {{plx1, plx2}, {ply1, ply2}}],  {av1 , lav1, uav1}, {av2 , lav2, uav2},{av3 , lav3, uav3}, ...{avn , lavn, uan}]
```

(of course the three dots are not really code but just their to indicate the idea that i want to be able to stack as many manipulate variables as possible).

The strategy that I came up with is as follows: I can condense the manipulation variables into one variable by starting with the , 
     List[av1 , lav1, uav1, av2 , lav2, uav2, av3 , lav3, uav3, ...avn , lavn, uan]

Then  hit the list with

```
   Partition[List[av1 , lav1, uav1, av2 , lav2, uav2, av3 , lav3, uav3, ...avn ,       lavn, uan],3]
```

Which give the list,

```
   {{av1 , lav1, uav1}, {av2 , lav2, uav2},{av3 , lav3, uav3}, ...{avn , lavn, uan}}.
```

However I can not put the code in like that so I must turn this list into a sequence, for which the following is used:

```
  l2s[{}] := Sequence[]; l2s[L_] := Sequence[First[L], l2s[Rest[L]]]
```

I then attempt to flatten my code with the following:

```
  Cman[fun_, var_, ldv_, udv_, plx1_, plx2_, ply1_, ply2_, L__ ] := 
  Manipulate[Plot[fun, {var, ldv, udv}, PlotRange -> {{plx1, plx2}, {ply1, ply2}}], 
  l2s[Partition[List[L], 3]]].
```

This gives however gives me the following error:

> Manipulate::vsform: "Manipulate argument l2s[Partition[{a,0,1},3]] does not have the correct form for a variable specification"

My question is therefore twofold:
1) is their a way to make it work through the error, since

```
 l2s[Partition[List[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3]]
```

give the output
       Sequence[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}]?

2) Is their another better way to do this?

I want to know if I can make my approach work, so I can better understand the program. For the same reason, I am also interested in better alternatives.

Note: For my practical purposes, the following code is pretty good.

```
  custman[fun_, var_, ldv_, udv_, plx1_, plx2_, ply1_, ply2_, L1__] := 
  Manipulate[
  Plot[fun, {var, ldv, udv}, 
  PlotRange -> {{plx1, plx2}, {ply1, ply2}}], L1].
```

However one must use the function as follows,

```
 custman[a x^2 + b, x, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 9, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
```

I want use the function in the following way:

```
 custman[a x^2 + b, x, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 9, a, 0, 1, b, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Try `Evaluate[Sequence @@ Partition[{L1}, 3]]`

Comment: I think one is better off writing `{a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1},...` but one is entitled to one's own taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simon Woods, in his comment, gave you the code pattern you need. Here is an example of it applied to a somewhat simpler `Manipulate`. It shouldn't be too difficult to generalize.

```
custom[obj_, ctrls__] :=
 Manipulate[
   obj,
   Evaluate[Sequence @@ Partition[{ctrls}, 3]]]
custom[a x^2 + b, a, 0, 1, b, 0, 1]
```

[image: manip.png]