# How can I predefine the variable ranges used within a Manipulate?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I would like to use a Manipulate environment with a large number of manipulable (?) variables, say `{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1},{x3,0,3}`,etc. Rather than define them all directly in the `Manipulate[]`, I'd like to define them ahead of a time, in a different cell.

How do I do this? The obvious solution, to make a list of ranges:

```
ranges={{x1,0,1},{x2,0,1},{x3,0,3}};
Manipulate[f(x1,x2,x3), ranges]
```

doesn't work, presumably because of the outer braces. But there appears to be no way to pull out the contents of the list without putting them in a new list; for instance `ranges[[All]]` returns `ranges` itself rather than its contents. But `ranges[[1]]` works just fine, that's *not* a list with one element but rather the element itself. Is there a way to get all of the elements out of `ranges` for use inside a `Manipulate`?

Comment: `Manipulate[f[x1, x2, x3], Sequence @@ ranges // Evaluate]`

Comment: @march:  Fine answer.  I suggest you post it so it can be accepted and others not be drawn to this (solved) question.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Except, I'm almost certain that this is a duplicate question, I just can't find it.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Well, maybe [this one in the Related sidebar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37527/how-can-i-pass-in-parameters-for-multiple-controls-to-a-function-that-returns-a?rq=1) (although it's a little more complicated).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments. I saw the "possible duplicate" and decided it wasn't one; if the powers that be think I'm wrong that's fine. Seconding the request for the answer to be posted as such so that I can mark it.